# How to create a merge request from an already pushed commit from CLI?

Tags: git, gitlab, git-merge, merge-request

I have a branch called `dev` which is up-to-date with the `origin/dev`. I want to merge into the (protected) `master` with the following command, but it doesn't push either create the merge request.

```
$ git push -o merge_request.create -o merge_request.target=master
Everything up-to-date
```

How to create a merge request from an already pushed commit from CLI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution is based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61507660/2506522), but mine is more general. The solution below creates a custom-named branch to push it, and it requests the delete of the newly created branch on merge.

```sh
# Create new unique merge-request branch ex: 1234abc-to-master
git checkout -b `git rev-parse --short HEAD`"-to-master"

# Create merge request with upstream this new branch
git push -u origin `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD` -o merge_request.create -o merge_request.target=master -o merge_request.remove_source_branch
```

Answer (score 3):

If your `dev` branch is up to date with the `dev` branch on origin, your `git push` command won't do anyting, because `Everything up-to-date`.

To create the merge request from CLI, create a new branch (from `dev`) to make the push happen:

```
git checkout -b dev2
git push -o merge_request.create -o merge_request.target=master
```

Comment: With `merge_request.remove_source_branch` option this is a good solution. Otherwise, there will be a branch flood.

Comment: Good catch. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to automate merge request creation, but wanted to do the push 1st and later on to create the actual merge request. I have used this trick to do it, after the original push went to the remote:

```
git commit --amend --no-edit
git push --force-with-lease  origin [branch_name] -o merge_request.create -o merge_request.target=master
```

The amend will keep the original commit unchanged, and allow you to push the same branch while creating the merge request.